Does shuffling the training data cause information leakage in a time-series model with image sequences?
I am working on a predictive model for solar power production based on image sequences captured at 10-minute intervals. A single example my model receives as input consists of a sequence of images. My architecture combines CNNs and LSTMs, the CNN processes the image sequence to extract features, which are then passed to the LSTM to make use of the temporal information from the image sequence.
I am using a 10 min forecast interval, with images in 10 min resolution. Hence, each image (except for first few and last few) will occur in multiple sequences. Example of an input batch:

I am wondering whether shuffling the training data (i.e., shuffling the overall order of the image sequences, not the images within a sequence) during training can cause information leakage. My concern is that during training, the model might already have seen "future" images while predicting the "current" target, which could violate the temporal structure of the data. I don't provide any explicit timestamps or previous target values in the input, simply the image sequences.
By shuffling, I am hoping for better gradient updates and better batch normalization.
Edit:
The plots below show the training (MSE) loss. The upper plot represents results without shuffling, while the lower plot includes shuffling. Each plot includes four independent runs to account for variations due to initialization.

Early stopping with a patience of 2 epochs was applied based on the validation loss, resulting in varying run lengths.

I've asked this in the Data Science forum as well (no answers yet)

My  last answer missed the point, so I deleted it. It referred to whether you should shuffle your data in cross validation or not. There, you should not do it.

Can you be more specific about your response? Is it the power production of any of these 10 minute intervals?

@ChrisL no worries, thank you for your efforts! Yes, every image has a corresponding solar power production value, with both recorded at 10-minute intervals. The goal is to use the prior 6 images (e.g., from 10:00 to 10:50) to predict the solar power production value 10 minutes into the future (e.g., at 11:00). The first plot highlights this setup.

I assume by 'information leakage' you mean 'data leakage' which, according to Wikipedia, is

... the use of information in the model training process which would not be expected to be available at prediction time

If you simply shuffle the elements in your training data (and don't add or take or remove some, let alone shuffle them together with some test or validation dataset) then you don't leak data/information to the model which wouldn't be available at prediction time.
You are correct that your model might have already seen some future images before in training, but this happens in most machine learning trainings: If you do more than one epoch, your model will inevitably see data again which it already has seen before. If this is an issue, I would say that you are over-fitting, not leaking data.

Just to be verbose about a point. If your test data set (used for unbiased evaluation of the model) would have leaked (in parts) to the training data set, then you should expect your tests performance to be optimistically biased (you seem to be very good on the test set, although you are not if no test data would have been leaked to the training set)
